# When does javascript stop running on a page after a link is clicked?

Tags: javascript

I have a page which runs various javascript code, including calling `setTimeout()`. If a user clicks a link to navigate to another page, at what point does the javascript on this page stop running and therefore my code called by setTimeout will no longer be called? e.g.

- as soon as the link is clicked (I know this is wrong)
- when the browser starts receiving the new page
- some other point?

And is this different for the different major browsers?

**Background**

I want to know this largely for interest's sake rather than to solve any particular problem. The problem which prompted me to think about this is I'd like to do something when a user clicks a particular link on a page. I want to perform an ajax call and process the result, but I'm not too concerned if it finishes before the page is unloaded. So I'll fire a setTimeout() on the link click and then if I'm lucky it'll finish but if I'm not it won't. I wondered in what circumstances it'll work. While there may be other solutions to that problem, I don't want solutions to the problem I only want to know the answer to the question.

Comment: Probably just after the [onunload event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onunload), but why is that important to you?

Comment: The *active timers* (which `setTimeout` adds to) are cleared during the [`unloading document cleanup steps`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#unloading-document-cleanup-steps), which are called from (amongst others) the [`unload document procedure`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#unload-a-document). Yet I'm not sure when exactly these are called during a [navigation process](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#navigating-across-documents)

Comment: A similar question could be: "Can my Javascript/jQuery/AJAX delay loading a link the user clicked." For example, I click a link and while waiting for the link to load, I'm still seeing stuff fly by in my Firebug console! Then the question is, which page is responsible for the unresponsive behavior, the source or destination?

Answer (score 3):

Here's the sequence of what happens:

Step 1: You click on a link. Here the browser sends a request to the server and waits for the response. The current page's document object still exists.

Step 2: Browser receives the response. The current page's document objects still exists.

Step 3: The browser parses, creates and renders the response to a new document object.

Step 3 is when the current page's JS will stop, UNLESS, you have targeted the response to an iframe, for example. If you do that, then the new document object will be rendered inside the iframe and the current page's document object remains intact and JS will still remain functional.

Hope that answers your question!

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any references to describe in more detail?

Comment: I think the old DOM is unloaded even before the browser receives a response? What makes you think that this is the sequence, do you have any references?

Comment: Is there a way to detect if the user is waiting for a link to respond?  Ex: "If user not trying to leave, do more busy work."

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be to stop the click event, fire away an asynchronous call and resume the default event when the result from the ajax call has been processed. Or, if possible, you could handle the processing on the server in which case you wouldn't even need to stop the default event - just fire your asynchronous call.

In answer to your question, I agree with Jack that the script would stop run after the onunload event.

Hope this hepls.