# Does Google Analytics event tracking work when attaching a click event to a link?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

Let me preface this by saying that I know how handle link tracking either with the URL Builder or even a `ga()` callback with a `window.location` (while preventing the default action).

My understanding is that when clicking a link, the browser stops executing javascript (in which case the `ga()` function wouldn't execute). Can someone confirm that this is correct?

Comment: A very useful GA debugger (made by GA): https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna

Comment: @Johan Thanks. I just tested this and it did track the link. My understanding that js stopped executing immediately on click [was incorrect](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16478446/1822096).